# SQL - "merge" 3 tables with JOIN

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I want to select users from a table depending from two relation tables

The Structure:

```
[user]

uid | firstname | lastname | ...
---------------------------------
482 | USERa     | USERa    | ...
885 | USERb     | USERb    | ...
405 | USERc     | USERc    | ...
385 | USERd     | USERd    | ...

[news_info]

uid_local   | uid_foreign
--------------------------------
125         | 482       
100         | 405       

[news_add]

uid_local   | uid_foreign
--------------------------------
125         | 885   
105         | 385
```

Now i want to select only USERa and USERb via uid_local -> 125, from [news_info] and [news_add]

```
SELECT 
  nnfo.uid_local, 
  user.* 
FROM user
  JOIN news_info nnfo
    ON nnfo.uid_foreign = user.uid
WHERE nnfo.uid_local = 125
```

result = USERa // works

```
SELECT 
  nadd.uid_local,
  user.* 
FROM user
  JOIN news_add nadd
    ON nadd.uid_foreign = user.uid
WHERE nadd.uid_local = 125
```

result = USERb // works

now "merge" the sql statement into one...to get USERa and USERb

```
SELECT 
  nnfo.uid_local, 
  nadd.uid_local,
  user.* 
FROM user
  JOIN news_info nnfo
    ON nnfo.uid_foreign = user.uid
  JOIN news_add nadd
    ON nadd.uid_foreign = user.uid
WHERE nnfo.uid_local = 125 AND nadd.uid_local = 125
```

result = empty // no errors.....

what is wrong...i tryed some other statements but with no result :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When merging results of queries, there are 2 different approaches:

- UNION
- JOINs

To know which one to choose you have to know whether there's a technical link between tables in the 2 queries you wish to merge. In your case, there's a *functional* link (`nnfo.uid_local = 125 AND nadd.uid_local = 125`) but it's not enough to join these 2 universes. You still *could* get the result with only one `SELECT`, but I think the final result would be unclear and somehow not really in the spirit of what SQL provides.

I'd go towards the UNION solution:

```
SELECT 
  nnfo.uid_local, 
  user.* 
FROM user
  JOIN news_info nnfo
    ON nnfo.uid_foreign = user.uid
WHERE nnfo.uid_local = 125 
UNION
SELECT 
  nadd.uid_local,
  user.* 
FROM user
  JOIN news_add nadd
    ON nadd.uid_foreign = user.uid
WHERE nadd.uid_local = 125
```

Edit: I see davek's result implements `UNION ALL` instead of `UNION`. I assumed you wished to return USERa only once if it happened to appear in both independant queries, that's why I used the simple `UNION` operator vs the `UNION ALL` that would return duplicate results as well.

Comment: whats the logical  difference b/w your answer and davek's answer ?

Comment: I don't think there's any, besides the UNION ALL thing

Comment: thanks davek and Sebas...with UNION only not UNION ALL i get my results with no duplicates as you said :)

Answer (score 2):

Your `uid_local` IDs exist on different rows: so when you want to AND the results, you get nothing (as nothing intersects). You could do it with a union:

```
SELECT * from
(
SELECT 
  nnfo.uid_local, 
  user.firstname, user.lastname 
FROM user
  JOIN news_info nnfo
    ON nnfo.uid_foreign = user.uid
WHERE nnfo.uid_local = 125 

UNION ALL

SELECT 
  nadd.uid_local,
  user.firstname, user.lastname 
FROM user
  JOIN news_add nadd
    ON nadd.uid_foreign = user.uid
WHERE nadd.uid_local = 125
) x
```

Comment: this works but i can only do this  with two SELECT statements?

Comment: @Jim: see my edit: you can do it in one by wrapping with an outer SELECT.

Comment: yes ...but this means that i have three SELECT's im not sure that this is efficient